# No output when running TensorFlow through Visual Studios with Python Tools

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

I have my Visual Studio's setup with Python Tools and CPython installed.

Running a sample "Hello World!" program shows that Python is setup correctly in Visual Studios and the messages prints out.

However, I am looking to use Visual Studio as my IDE of choice for working with TensorFlow. I have imported all necessary packages. yet when running a sample TensorFlow program as shown below, the running window simply displays a black screen.

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(hello))
print("hey")
```

There are no errors shown, no messages hence I am unsure what exactly is missing or not setup correctly.

Comment: There's no obvious explanation for this, so I have a few follow-up questions: 1. Can you run TensorFlow in a standalone Python session (e.g. using the Command Prompt)? 2. Does Visual Studio use the same version of Python as the one you have installed? 3. At what point does it fail (i.e. what happens if you run one line at a time)?

Comment: 1) Tensorflow runs fine using the CMD when i enter the lines one by one per the "Test the TensorFlow installation" guide. 2) Visual Studio is following the same version of Python (64-bit v3.5) i have installed. 3) I have managed to gather that the program stops upon importing the TensorFlow package as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427951/importing-tensorflow-stops-python-program-from-running

Comment: Me too am facing the same issue when I press F5 and start in debug mode. Though it come up but still takes time. Have you overcome the issue? If so how? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and turns out it was not really a problem! It actually works but it takes a noticeably long time to show you something so you might think its not working! Just give it a few minutes and you will see the output. Still I have the problem of very slow processing time which I don't know how to approach. Could be a VS problem.

Comment: a few minutes is not an acceptable response if you are prototyping. It seems to work fine in interactive. :S