# Importing TensorFlow stops python program from running

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

I have Python Tools setup in Visual Studios with CPython installed.

In Visual Studios, if i run the following code:

```
print("hello");
import numpy;
print("hello");
```

The program runs fine, prints two 'hello', and exits normally.

However, if I run the following code:

```
print("hello");
import tensorflow;
print("hello");
```

The program hangs, prints one 'hello', and refuses to continue.

All packages should be correctly installed - using the TensorFlow in the Python interactive window prints the correct output and works perfectly.

Why does the program hang in the second scenario?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your CPU setup. Check my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424358/no-output-when-running-tensorflow-through-visual-studios-with-python-tools/44493189#44493189

Comment: Check my response below. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424358/no-output-when-running-tensorflow-through-visual-studios-with-python-tools/44493189#44493189

Answer (score 0):

Once you import tensorflow it automatically tries to load cuda, it prints something like this:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

So I think what is happening is that you don't have cuda installed correctly and it is failing because of it. You can try to install the CPU version which doesn't use the GPU and doesn't load those libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have checked and resinstalled the tensorflow package - I am running the CPU variant of the library.